# Evaluation of linear expression with docplex based on a solution

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, docplex, cp-sat

For a `CpModel` using docplex, is there any function to evaluate a linear expression based on the variables values in the final solution?

For example, for `expression = (x + 2y + z)`, with Gurobi this expression has type `gurobipy.LinExpr` and I can do `expression.getValue()`. For CP-SAT of OrTools I can do `solver.Value(expression)` where solver has type `CpSolver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, it seems that as of today there is no way to get the value of a general linear expression that was not previously defined in the model before solving it. I found the same question here https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/extract-the-solution-value-for-expression-in-cp and apparently the best solution is to add the expression as a pre-defined KPI to the model.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your model object is `mdl`, when you create the constraints in docplex with `add_constraint` (or `add_constraints`), the generated constraint is returned and you can save that, similar to what you showed in your example.

For example:

`ctr = mdl.add_constraint(x+y<=5, 'c1')`
If your constraint is not saved, you can access it after the solve by `ctr = mdl.get_constraint_by_name('c1')` as well.

Now, what's the value that you're after? If it's `x+y`, then you're after the `lhs`. So, to get that expression, you can say `ctr.lhs` (Similarly, you can access `rhs` using `ctr.rhs`). If you want to get the value, it's like getting any other value in docplex, by accessing `solution_value`. So, the value of `x+y` becomes `ctr.lhs.solution_value`. There might be other ways, but this is the one that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something more generic though, not necessarily for an expression that is the lhs of a constraint.